# Using the C++ Actor Framewok with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, actor, distributed-computing, c++-actor-framework

I am trying to make a distributed vision system by using the C++ Actor Framework and OpenCV. I started with a proof of concept code that compiles but while running the "edges" window is created but do not display anything (code shown hereafter).

I really do not understand why it do not work, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

PS Code

main.cpp

```
#include <vector>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

#include "caf/all.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace caf;
using namespace std;

struct Image {
    Image(Mat mat = Mat()) {
        data.assign(mat.datastart,mat.dataend);
        type = mat.type();
        rows = mat.rows;
        cols = mat.cols;
    }

    Mat toMat() const {
        return Mat(rows,cols,type,(void *)data.data());
    }

    vector<uchar> data;
    int type;
    int rows;
    int cols;
};

bool operator==(const Image& lhs, const Image& rhs) {
    return  lhs.data == rhs.data
            && lhs.type == rhs.type
               && lhs.rows == rhs.rows
                  && lhs.cols == rhs.cols;
}

class VideoCaptureActor : public event_based_actor{
    VideoCapture cap;
    actor buddy;
protected:
    behavior make_behavior() override {
        send(this,get_atom::value);
        return {
                [=](get_atom){
                    while(true){
                        Mat frame;
                        cap >> frame;
                        this->send(buddy,put_atom::value,Image(frame));
                        if(waitKey(60) >= 0){
                            send(this,ok_atom::value);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                },
                [=](ok_atom){
                    cout << "Hello "<< buddy.id() <<" !"<<endl;
                },
                others >> [=](){
                    cerr << "unexpected: " << to_string(this->current_message()) << buddy.id() << endl;
                }

        };
    }

public:
    VideoCaptureActor(const actor &buddy){
        this->buddy = buddy;
        cap.open(0);
        if(!cap.isOpened())
            throw -1;
    }
};

class CannyActor : public event_based_actor {
    Mat edges;
protected:
    behavior make_behavior() override {
        return {
                [=](put_atom,Image image){
                    cvtColor(image.toMat(), edges, CV_BGR2GRAY);
                    GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
                    Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);
                    imshow("edges", edges);
                },
                others >> [=] {
                    cerr << "unexpected: " << to_string(this->current_message()) << endl;
                }

        };
    }
public:
    CannyActor(){
        namedWindow("edges",1);
    }
};

int main(int, char**) {
    announce<Image>("Image",&Image::data,&Image::type,&Image::rows,&Image::cols);
    try {
        spawn<VideoCaptureActor>(spawn<CannyActor>());
    }catch(int x){
        cerr<<x<<endl;
    }
    await_all_actors_done();
    shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(SmartVision CXX)

set (CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(Libcaf COMPONENTS core io REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11  -Wextra -Wall -pedantic")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG          "-O0 -g")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL     "-Os")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE        "-O4")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "-O2 -g")

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${LIBCAF_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(SmartVision ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(SmartVision ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${LIBCAF_LIBRARIES})
```

I placed also the FindLibcaf.cmake file in my project root folder in order to enable cmake to find the CAF libraries

I am using MacOS X Yosemite with CLion 1.0.2 as IDE
When running the program use a lot of CPU ressources: I have heard the fan of my macbook for the first time when it runs ! CAF is supposed to be a lightweight framework but perhaps I am using it in the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I have no experience with OpenCV. So I can only help figuring out what's happening on the CAF side of things.

Actors are supposed to be asynchronous, nonblocking and cooperative. The `while (true)` loop in `VideoCaptureActor` blocks a worker thread in the scheduler of CAF. Is it safe to call `imshow` in a different thread each time? Because this is what can end up happening to `CannyActor`. So it might just boil down to threading issues in OpenCV.

The first thing I would suggest doing is:

```
spawn<VideoCaptureActor, detached>(spawn<CannyActor, detached>());
```

This will assign a dedicated thread to each of your two actors.

As long as you're not sending the image over network, it is safe to just send the `Mat` directly (and not announce it) for now to see if the back-and-forth conversion with `Image` broke something. You can also write a custom serializer at some point in the future that allows you to serialize/deserialize `Mat` directly.

```
[=](get_atom) {
  while (true) {
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame;
    send(buddy, put_atom::value, std::move(frame));
    if(waitKey(60) >= 0){
      send(this, ok_atom::value);
      break;
    }
  }
},
```

In case `Mat` has no move constructor, you could store the frame in a `std::shared_ptr<Mat>` or something like that to get rid of the extra copy completely (at the extend of an additional heap allocation + indirection).

I hope that helps.